# How to get parent's children in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

this is my HTML file :

```
<a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable" style="top: 703px; bottom: -791px; z-index: 1; left: 0%; right: 0%;">

 <div class="fc-content"><div class="fc-time" data-start="4:00" data full="4:00 PM"><span>4:00</span></div>
   <div class="fc-title">Work Order 1003</div>
    <div class="fc-bg"></div>
     <div class="fc-resizer"></div>

</a>
```

I got the children content 'div.fc-title' using this code line `$('div').on('click', 'div.fc-content', function(e) {    alert($(this).children('.fc-title').text())`

On the other hand, I couldn't get it from the parent 'a' down to 'fc-title'.

Comment: Which code you tried is failing?

Comment: please layout your HTML code so that it's not all on one line

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nxf9vaqb/1/

Comment: @A. Wolff  I tried this $('a').on('click', 'div.fc-content', function(e) { alert($(this).children('.fc-title').text())

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid, missing a `</div>` closing tag and `data full="4:00 PM"` should be `data-full="4:00 PM"`.   Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/njcr4oqs/

Comment: @ A. Wolff  Still not working as I want, can i get this div content  '<div class="fc-title">Work Order 1003</div>' when pressing on the same level children '<div class="fc-bg"></div>' ????

Answer (score 1):

You could try to bind the handler to `document` object instead

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.fc-content', function (e) {
    alert($(this).children('.fc-title').text())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nxf9vaqb/)

Answer (score 0):

A minor modification to your script and it's done!

JS:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
alert($(this).children('.fc-title').text());
});
```

[Fiddle here...](http://jsfiddle.net/fw4gt8p4/)